# Image sizes for VHR remote sensing image

Tags: remote-sensing

I need to compare three or four different segmentation algorithms on very high spatial resolution remote sensing images, with a range between [0.31,1.00] meters/pixel.

What image size could you recommend to me?
Maybe 100x100, 500x500, 1000x1000 or other size?

Comment: The remote sensing images that I would use are WorldView3 (0.31 m/pixel), GeoEye1 (0.5 m/pixel), Aerial (1.0 m/pixel)